# Yoast SEO Generating blank sitemap

Tags: php, wordpress

I am having trouble in generating site map for my site.

I have latest version of yoast SEO plugin 3.5 and WordPress 4.6.1

I have tried different methods available on google but still cannot fix. Even disabled all other plugins. Changed the permalinks to postname but could not be fixed.

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[How do I get the directory where a Bash script is located from within the script itself?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/can-a-bash-script-tell-what-directory-its-stored-in)

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. Without installing any new plugin, update your current cache plugin(in my case "WP-Fastest cache")!

Also in this page there are more information:

https://kb.yoast.com/kb/xml-sitemap-errors